# Why can't i see the layer on the reciving computer?

Tags: python, networking, scapy, network-protocols

I tried to build a new layer in scapy but when i send the packet to another computer the new layer got lost. i put the next code on the sending computer and reciving computer.

```
import  sys 
i, o, e = sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr
from scapy.all import *

sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr = i, o, e
from scapy.packet import *
from scapy.fields import *
from scapy.layers.inet import UDP, IP
from scapy.layers.dns import DNS
from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether

vxlanmagic = "0x8"


class Vxlan(Packet):
    name = "Virtual eXtensible Local Area Network"
    fields_desc = [ByteField("flag", 8),
                   X3BytesField("reserved1", 0),
                   X3BytesField("vni", 0),
                   ByteField("reserved2", 0)]

    def guess_payload_class(self, payload):
        if self.flag == vxlanmagic:
            return Vxlan
        else:
            return Packet.guess_payload_class(self, payload)

    def mysummary(self):
        return self.sprintf("VXLAN (vni=%VXLAN.vni%)")

split_layers(UDP, DNS, sport=53)
bind_layers(UDP, Vxlan, dport=4789)
bind_layers(Vxlan, Ether)
packet = IP(dst='192.168.1.28')/Vxlan()
packet.show()
send(packet)
```

Comment: The same code i.e. same `dst` on both computers?

Comment: ohh, i mean the same class and code apper in both computer but this is the code on the sending computer, on the another there is sniff function instead sending and ceatring packet function. I also change the ip too

Comment: So, how do you know it got lost?

Comment: when i asked the reciving computer to print the reciving packet it print the packet except the new layer

Comment: Somebody can help??

Comment: FYI VXLAN is supported in Scapy now!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with a minor change, since you binded `Vxlan` to `UDP` on `dport=4789`, you will have to construct your packet such that it uses `UDP(dport=4789)`. So actually you can do:

```
packet = IP(dst='192.168.1.28')/UDP(dport=4789)/Vxlan()
```

and now it should work! Also remember [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258349/how-to-create-new-layer-or-new-protocol-with-scapy/46263621#46263621), that also the packet's target, must be aware of your layer.